# vue-authenticate: Where is the $auth variable defined?

Tags: vue.js, vue-authenticate

I am trying to implement [vue-authenticate](https://github.com/dgrubelic/vue-authenticate), but I'm having an issue with the following example code taken from their documentation:

```
new Vue({
  methods: {
    login: function () {
      this.$auth.login({ email, password }).then(function () {
        // Execute application logic after successful login
      })
    },

    register: function () {
      this.$auth.register({ name, email, password }).then(function () {
        // Execute application logic after successful registration
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Where is the `$auth` property coming from? I can't see it defined anywhere. I've looked through the documentation, and the example code in the repo, but neither provide any help.

Comment: It comes [from here](https://github.com/dgrubelic/vue-authenticate/blob/master/src/index.js#L18). It should be defined after you call `Vue.use(VueAuthenticate, options)`. If you are looking to address the specific error, please include more details about the error you're getting.

Comment: @Thebluefish I'm getting $auth is undefined. I have used `Vue.use` and added the authenticate method following the docs. I can't post a new question for 90 minutes now so I'm going to give Google/docs another try.

Comment: are you trying to reference `this.$auth` in the callback function passed to `then`? Or are you using arrow functions (`=>`) anywhere? Because you could be referencing the incorrect `this`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484

Comment: You guessed it, the problem was I was using arrow function on the top level `methods` functions. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know vue-authenticate is a Vue-plugin.

And when you use this plugin using the line.

```
Vue.use(VueAuthenticate, ...data)
```

And this is where it gets defined in [this file](https://github.com/dgrubelic/vue-authenticate/blob/master/src/index.js)

```
Object.defineProperties(Vue.prototype, {
  $auth: {
    get() {
      if (!vueAuthInstance) {
        // Request handler library not found, throw error
        if (!this.$http) {
          throw new Error('Request handler instance not found')
        }

        vueAuthInstance = new VueAuthenticate(this.$http, options)
      }
      return vueAuthInstance
    }
  }
})
```

Also you may want to go through this documentation on  [Adding Instance Properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html).